# SQL convert varchar into money

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to calculate the total cost of items and and having that value into a new column called cost.

In my creation script the values are in characters but the data type is money.

```
CREATE VIEW ordered_pizzas_view
AS 
    SELECT 
        orderpizza_id, order_id, ..., 
        CONCAT(range_price, ' ', crust_surcharge, ' ', sauce_surcharge) AS 'cost'
    FROM 
        order_pizza 
    INNER JOIN 
        ...
    WHERE 
        'cost' = (SELECT SUM(CAST(range_price AS MONEY)) FROM pizza_range) +
                 (SELECT SUM(CAST(crust_surcharge AS MONEY)) FROM crust) +
                 (SELECT SUM(CAST(Sauce_surcharge AS MONEY)) FROM sauce)
```

Comment: Did you check the values in the table, are there non-numeric entries?

Comment: I just noticed the SQL syntax is wrong, you can not compare money with char..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you expecting from `concat()`? `concat()` returns a string value which based on your input is going to be three money values separated by a space, e.g. `$1.00 $2.00 $0.50`

Comparing that to a money value is going to throw an error. Perhaps you meant to just add the values?

```
(range_price + crust_surcharge + sauce_surcharge ) as [cost]
```

Note: Do not use string literals as aliases.

---

Also, your `where` clause is comparing a string literal (`'cost'`) to a `money` data type from the combined subqueries.

```
where --'cost'
      (range_price + crust_surcharge + sauce_surcharge )
              = (select Sum(CAST(range_price as money)) from pizza_range) 
             + ( select Sum(CAST(crust_surcharge as money)) from crust ) 
             + ( select Sum(CAST(Sauce_surcharge as money)) from sauce )
```

Note: You can not use column aliases in the `where` clause, you must repeat the expression or reference the expression from a subquery/derived table or other operator.

Comment: Thanks SQLZim that answered one of my problems, much appreciated